# Rebuild this without js parent function. Change it to specyfic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rebuild this without .parent because i have trouble when i connect this in wordpress. I want in js add and remove specyfic classes without using parent. Change parent to specyfic class. How i can do that? 
Can i save funcionality of this without .parent function in js?

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');

$contents.slice().hide();

$('.tab').click(function() {
 removeNewClass();
  
  var id = this.id;
  var $target = $('#' + id + 'show').show();
  var newClass = 'long';

  $(this).hide().parent().addClass(newClass);
  $('.tab').show();
  $contents.not($target).hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
 removeNewClass();

  $(this).parent().hide();
  $(this).parent().prev('.tab').show();

  var $target = $(this).parent();
});

function removeNewClass(){
  $contents.each(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var postClass = 'post' + id.split('tab')[1];
    console.log( postClass );
    $(this).parent().attr("class", postClass);
  });
}
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.long {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post1">
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, optio.</div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium deserunt vel in.</p>
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post2">
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae non sequi, itaque?</p>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    content 2
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problems do you have using .parent()?  You could use .parentNode (pure JS, not jQuery) but unless you show what problems you're having with the current implementation I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to help you solve them!

Comment: Hey man this is great but i want to remove class .long when i click close button: https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/68/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently where I was encountering some weird bugs while using `.parent()`. To combat this, I used data attributes.

More specifically, I set a `data-target` attribute on the closing button that contained a query of the element that I wanted to close. This query can then be easily passed to jQuery to find the exact element you want on the page. It's much more accurate and consistent compared to using relative elements.

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
$contents.hide();

var newClass = 'long';

$('.tab').click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target'));

  $target.addClass(newClass);

  $target.find('.tab-content').show();
  $target.find('.tab').hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target'));

  $target.removeClass(newClass);

  $target.find('.tab-content').hide();
  $target.find('.tab').show();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.long {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post1">
  <h2>Title 1</h2>
  <div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, optio.</div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab" data-target=".post1">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium deserunt vel in.</p>
    <div class="close" data-target=".post1">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post2">
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae non sequi, itaque?</p>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab" data-target=".post2">Show 2</div>
  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    content 2
    <div class="close" data-target=".post2">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx but can you do the same on this? How remove long class when click close? https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/75/

Comment: BIG THANK YOU Man!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for?

```js
var $contents = $('.tab-content');

$contents.slice().hide();

$('.tab').click(function() {
 removeNewClass();
  
  var id = this.id;
  var $target = $('#' + id + 'show').show();
  var newClass = 'long';

  $('.tab').show();

  $(this).hide()[0].parentNode.classList.add(newClass);

  $contents.not($target).hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  removeNewClass();

  var parent = $(this.parentNode);

  parent
    .hide()
    .prev('.tab')
    .show();
});

function removeNewClass(){
  $contents.each(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var postClass = 'post' + id.split('tab')[1];
    console.log( postClass );
    $(this.parentNode).attr("class", postClass);
  });
}
```

```css
.tab {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.long {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post1">
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, optio.</div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Show 1</div>
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium deserunt vel in.</p>
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post2">
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae non sequi, itaque?</p>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">Show 2</div>
  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    content 2
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This is great but you can hide this red div with text Show 1 or Show 2 dynamicaly when clicked it? When click close show it again ok?

Comment: Thank you but you can the same on this? https://jsfiddle.net/udr01vsq/72/

Comment: ok but class long when i click close is still active. Can we remove this class when i click close specyfic accordion?